# ResultSet.getNext() not working with PreparedStatement

Tags: java, oracle, jdbc, plsql

I am trying to figure out why ResultSet.next() is never true in Java code that I am writing after I execute a SQL query that returns results from an Oracle 11g table into that ResultSet... it seems as though the code does not pick up a returned ResultSet's contents correctly when using a PreparedStatement in a java.sql.Connection.  Any help appreciated, here are the details:

Table:

```
  CREATE TABLE "SHANDB"."ABSCLOBS" 
   (    "ID" NUMBER, 
    "XMLVAL" "XMLTYPE", 
    "IDSTRING" VARCHAR2(20 BYTE)
   )
```

Data:

```
INSERT INTO absclobs VALUES ( 1, 
   xmltype('<?xml version="1.0"?>
               <EMP>
                  <EMPNO>221</EMPNO>
                  <ENAME>John</ENAME>
               </EMP>', '1'));

INSERT INTO absclobs VALUES (2, 
   xmltype('<?xml version="1.0"?>
               <PO>
                  <PONO>331</PONO>
                  <PONAME>PO_1</PONAME>
               </PO>', '2'));
```

Java code I am running to get values from the above to test the code:

```
  public static void main(String[] args) throws Exception {
    try {
      String url = "jdbc:oracle:thin:@//localhost:1521/xe";
      String driver = "sun.jdbc.odbc.JdbcOdbcDriver";
      String user = "shandb";
      String password = "test";
      Class.forName(driver);
      connection = DriverManager.getConnection(url,user, password);
      String selectID1 = "SELECT a.xmlval.getClobval() AS poXML FROM absclobs a where idstring=? and id=? ";      
      PreparedStatement preparedStatement = connection.prepareStatement(selectID1);

      preparedStatement.setString(1, "1"); 
      preparedStatement.setInt(2, 1); 

      rowsUpdated = preparedStatement.executeQuery(); 
      while(rowsUpdated.next()){
          String clobxml = rowsUpdated.getString(1);
          System.out.println(clobxml);
      }
    } catch (ClassNotFoundException cnfe) {
      System.err.println(cnfe);
    } catch (SQLException sqle) {
      System.err.println(sqle);
    }
    finally{
        System.out.println("Rows affected: " + rowsUpdated);
        connection.close();     
    }

  }
```

This part of the above code is never run, which I don't understand:

```
  while(rowsUpdated.next()){
      String clobxml = rowsUpdated.getString(1);
      System.out.println(clobxml);
  }
```

... however the final print statement shows that the ResultSet is not empty:

```
Rows affected: oracle.jdbc.driver.OracleResultSetImpl@15f157b
```

Does anyone know why I can't display the actual retrieved XML clob contents, and/or why the while block above is never true?

Thanks :)

Comment: How does that line tell you that the ResultSet is not empty? Even an empty ResultSet is an object that resides at a memory adress, it just doesn't have any rows. It's not the same as a `null`.

Comment: us2012 is right. so did you try another query or did you test you query directly? does it have any rows at all?

Comment: There is way too much complexity in this question... Perhaps you should first cut all the non-relevant details (where conditions, etc) and check that works as expected. This will help all of us to nails down the problem faster.

Comment: Sorry... wh at I meant was that this statement returns a value, but the code running above does not, which I don't understand:  SELECT a.xmlval.getClobval() AS poXML FROM absclobs a where idstring='1' and id=1;

Comment: @fuzzyanalysis: So why did you introduce *anything* about the "final print statement"? And have you tried without the WHERE clause? And why don't your INSERT statements include an IDSTRING value?

Comment: Gah sorry, I had forgotten that I'd added the last IDSTRING values by hand using SQL Developer.  I've put them in the INSERT statements now, apologies.

Comment: @fuzzyanalysis: Again, have you tried without the `WHERE` clause at all?

Comment: Thanks for the answers about the ResultSet possibly being empty, as well as the idea to troubleshoot without parameters in the SQL first - I have learned something today!

Comment: Yes Jon, I've tried it and both rows are returned.  So the SQL is fine.

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5258366/how-to-determine-if-resultset-is-empty    ... I've re-written the Java to use Statement instead of PreparedStatement , and it works.  So the problem is the way that I am using PreparedStatement with the SQL.

Comment: OK I must have confused myself.  Somehow PreparedStatement is working now... thanks for the troubleshooting tips.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Your diagnostics are incorrect - this:

```
Rows affected: oracle.jdbc.driver.OracleResultSetImpl@15f157b
```

doesn't show that the result set is non-empty. It just shows that the value of `rowsUpdated` is a reference to an instance of `oracle.jdbc.driver.OracleResultSetImpl`, which doesn't override `toString()`. That can very easily be empty.

I suspect the problem is just that your `WHERE` clause doesn't match any records. For the sake of diagnostics, I suggest you change it to just:

```
String selectID1 = "SELECT a.xmlval.getClobval() AS poXML FROM absclobs a";
```

(and get rid of the parameter-setting calls, of course). That way you should be able to see *all* your table's values. You can then work on discovering why your `WHERE` clause wasn't working as expected.

(As an aside, it's not clear why you haven't declared `connection` or `rowsUpdated` in the code in the question. They should definitely be local variables...)

Comment: Heck, just run your intended call on it's own against your database, `SELECT a.xmlval.getClobval() AS poXML FROM absclobs a where idstring='1' and id=1` and see if you get anything back.  Also, if you're just referring to your columns returned back via the column index (1, in this case), you don't need the `AS poXML` portion of your query.

Comment: That's true, I don't need the AS part.  I messed up the question earlier by not putting in the IDSTRING values into the INSERT statements, which I've now fixed.  Problem still stands though, the SQL runs correctly to return one row, but the ResultSet.next() is never true.

Comment: It was weird solution in the end... whenever I removed any reference to the ResultSet that I was examining in my Eclipse "Expressions" tab, the above worked fine.  Add an expression that involved the ResultSet into the tab, and everything falls over.  Really odd.

Comment: @fuzzyanalysis: Hmm. That would make sense if `toString()` exhausted the `ResultSet` perhaps - but not otherwise. Odd. Oh well - at least it's fixed now...